# Jquery Ajax multiple dynamic forms and php processing don't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I have multiple dynamic forms (with php) where a can send an email with each one when i press the submit button. The problem is when i send the form information to php, with ajax. I'm doing something wrong, because the email doesn't show anything.

This is the code of every form:

```
<form action="enviar_cotizacion.php" method="post" id="form_<?php echo $articulos[3]; ?>" name="form_<?php echo $articulos[3]; ?>">
    <p class="pInlineBlock2">
        <label class="label_cotizacion">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txt_nombre" name="txt_nombre" class="txt_cotizacion" required/>
    </p>

    <p class="pInlineBlock2">
        <label class="label_cotizacion">Apellido:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txt_apellido" name="txt_apellido" class="txt_cotizacion" required/>
    </p>

    <p class="pInlineBlock2">
        <label class="label_cotizacion">Teléfono:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txt_tel" name="txt_tel" class="txt_cotizacion" required/>
    </p>

    <p class="pInlineBlock2">
        <label class="label_cotizacion">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txt_mail" name="txt_mail" class="txt_cotizacion" required/>
    </p>

    <p class="pInlineBlock2">
        <label class="label_cotizacion">Producto:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txt_servicio" name="txt_servicio" class="txt_cotizacion" required/>
    </p>

    <p class="pBlock">
        <label class="span_coti">Especificación Técnica:</label>
        <textarea id="txt_espec_tecnica" name="txt_espec_tecnica" class="txt_area_cotizacion" required></textarea>
    </p>

    <p class="pBlock"> <input type="submit" id="btn_aceptar" value="COTIZAR"/></p>
</form>
```

So, i have X amount of forms with different ID and name.

The following code is the validation of them.

```
$("form").each(function() {
$(this).validate({
    rules:{
        txt_nombre:{
            required:true,
            maxlength:140
        },
        txt_apellido:{
            required:true,
            maxlength:140
        },
        txt_tel:{
            required:true
        },
        txt_mail:{
            required:true,
            email: true
        },
        txt_servicio:{
            required:true,
            maxlength:140
        },
        txt_espec_tecnica:{
            required:true
        }
    },
    messages:{
        txt_nombre:{
            required:"Este dato es obligatorio.",
            maxlength:"El nombre no puede tener mas de 140 caracteres"
        },
        txt_apellido:{
            required:"Este dato es obligatorio.",
            maxlength:"El apellido no puede tener mas de 140 caracteres"
        },
        txt_tel:{
            required:"Este dato es obligatorio."
        },
        txt_mail:{
            required:"Este dato es obligatorio",
            email: "Escriba un email válido"
        },
        txt_servicio:{
            required:"Este dato es obligatorio.",
            maxlength:"El nombre no puede tener mas de 140 caracteres"
        },
        txt_espec_tecnica:{
            required:"Este dato es obligatorio."
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var nombre = $("#txt_nombre").val();
        var apellido = $("#txt_apellido").val();
        var email = $("#txt_mail").val();
        var telefono = $("#txt_tel").val();
        var producto = $("#txt_servicio").val();
        var espec_tecnica = $("#txt_espec_tecnica").val();
        var dataString = 'nombre=' + nombre + '&apellido=' + apellido + '&telefono=' + telefono + '&email=' + email+ '&producto=' + producto+ '&espec_tecnica=' + espec_tecnica;
        $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
            data: dataString,
            url:"enviar_cotizacion.php",
            success: function(){
              alert('Cotizacion enviada correctamente');
            },
            error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert('Error al enviar cotizacion');
            }
        });
        return false; // Temporary
    }
});
```

});

I have tried the *data: $(this).serialize()* function instead of *data: dataString*, but doesn't work either.

And the php code, very simple only for testing.

```
<?php
$nombre = $_POST['nombre']." ".$_POST['apellido'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$producto = $_POST['producto'];
$espec_tecnica = $_POST['espec_tecnica'];
$para = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx@dominio.com';
$titulo = 'Cotizacion';
$header = 'From: ' . $email;
$msjCorreo = "Nombre: $nombre\n E-Mail: $email\n Producto:\n $producto";
mail($para, $titulo, $msjCorreo, $header);
?>
```

So, if I put this on jquery code, on $.ajax():

```
var nombre = "james";
var apellido = "smith";
var email = "james@gmail.com";
var telefono = "123456";
var producto = "agitadores";
var espec_tecnica = "i want to know the price of this product, please";
var dataString = 'nombre=' + nombre + '&apellido=' + apellido + '&telefono=' + telefono + '&email=' + email+ '&producto=' + producto+ '&espec_tecnica=' + espec_tecnica;
```

I can receive an email with this data. But, if I try to get the information from the form I selected, I receive a blank email. Which is the problem? what am i doing wrong? Thanks for all your help.

=================================UPDATE===============================================
**Here is the solution!**

My error was on php and jquery code: Here you have the changes I made:

On js:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
        var dataString=$(form).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type    : 'POST',
            url     : 'enviar_cotizacion.php',// write code to send mail in mail.php
            data    : dataString,
            cache   : false,
            dataType: 'text',
            success : function (serverResponse) { 
                  alert('mail sent successfully.'); 
            },
            error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert('error sending mail');
            }
        });
        alert(dataString);
        return false; /*$// Temporary*/
    }
```

On php:

```
<?php
$nombre = $_POST['txt_nombre']." ".$_POST['txt_apellido'];
$telefono = $_POST['txt_tel'];
$email = $_POST['txt_mail'];
$producto = $_POST['txt_servicio'];
$espec_tecnica = $_POST['txt_espec_tecnica'];
$para = 'test@gmail.com';
$titulo = 'Cotizacion desde ASDF';
$header = 'From: ' . $email;
$msjCorreo = "Nombre: $nombre\n E-Mail: $email\n Producto:\n $producto";

mail($para, $titulo, $msjCorreo, $header);
?>
```

And that's it :) I hope this answer can be usefull for other people.

Comment: You can actually make an answer to your own post and later accept it.  I suggest you do that instead of editing the answer into your question.